# remoteLink can't find controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I can call the closure of a controller in a gsp view using the following link:

```
 <g:link url="${request.contextPath}/data/${params.name}/myController/myClosure">
 Text Goes Here
 </g:link>
```

However I would like to use remoteLink because I don't want to render anything, just perform a task.  Am I correct to want to use remoteLink?

Unfortunately remoteLink does not have a url attribute. So I use controller and action:

```
 <g:remoteLink controller="myController" action="myClosure">
 Text Goes Here
 </g:remoteLink>
```

Which unsuccessfully uses the url "/myApp/MyController/MyClosure", which is different from the url that works.

So my questions are,

1. How did my controller get that longer url?  It does not appear in my URLMappings.  What controls this?
2. Is there anyway I can use remoteLink to access that url?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL mapping must be named:

```
static mappings = {
   name <mapping name>: <url pattern> {
      // …
   }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
 <g:remoteLink mapping="<mapping name>" controller="myController" action="myClosure">
 Text Goes Here
 </g:remoteLink>
```